# В чем главная цель Factory Method (фабричного метода)?

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, теория

Цель фабричного метода я вижу в том что клиент передает объект с фабричным методом без создания объекта который создает фабричный метод,
таким образом мы не создаем если не надо и с другой стороны можем себе наклепать сколько угодно объектов.

Если фабричный метод представлен статическим классом в который не задается никакой информации до передачи в другой метод, то какой вообще смысл использовать фабрику.

Если там есть какие-то поля объекта/класса которые задаются до передачи, вызываются какие-то функции как в декораторе, то понятно зачем нужен паттерн, а здесь не совсем.

Я правильно понимаю что это основная выгода от создания фабричного метода? Потому что иначе я могу просто использовать new. Ещё приходит на ум мебель и её стили, допустим все настолько разное что паттерн Мост не вариант. Тогда я могу отнаследоваться от просто мебели и передать мебель нужного мне типа, а там когда надо создастся сколько надо мебели с нужным стилем.

В интернете вижу примеры как этого

```
public class SimpleItalianCoffeeFactory extends SimpleCoffeeFactory {

    @Override
    public Coffee createCoffee (CoffeeType type) {
        Coffee coffee = null;
        switch (type) {
            case AMERICANO:
                coffee = new ItalianStyleAmericano();
                break;
            case ESPRESSO:
                coffee = new ItalianStyleEspresso();
                break;
            case CAPPUCCINO:
                coffee = new ItalianStyleCappuccino();
                break;
            case CAFFE_LATTE:
                coffee = new ItalianStyleCaffeLatte();
                break;
        }
        return coffee;
    }
}

public class SimpleAmericanCoffeeFactory extends SimpleCoffeeFactory{

    @Override
    public Coffee createCoffee (CoffeeType type) {
        Coffee coffee = null;

        switch (type) {
            case AMERICANO:
                coffee = new AmericanStyleAmericano();
                break;
            case ESPRESSO:
                coffee = new AmericanStyleEspresso();
                break;
            case CAPPUCCINO:
                coffee = new AmericanStyleCappuccino();
                break;
            case CAFFE_LATTE:
                coffee = new AmericanStyleCaffeLatte();
                break;
        }

        return coffee;
    }

}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*
            Закажем капучино в итальянском стиле:
            1. Создадим фабрику для приготовления итальянского кофе
            2. Создадим новую кофейню, передав ей в конструкторе фабрику итальянского кофе
            3. Закажем наш кофе
         */
        SimpleItalianCoffeeFactory italianCoffeeFactory = new SimpleItalianCoffeeFactory();
        CoffeeShop italianCoffeeShop = new CoffeeShop(italianCoffeeFactory);
        italianCoffeeShop.orderCoffee(CoffeeType.CAPPUCCINO);


         /*
            Закажем капучино в американском стиле
            1. Создадим фабрику для приготовления американского кофе
            2. Создадим новую кофейню, передав ей в конструкторе фабрику американского кофе
            3. Закажем наш кофе
         */
        SimpleAmericanCoffeeFactory americanCoffeeFactory = new SimpleAmericanCoffeeFactory();
        CoffeeShop americanCoffeeShop = new CoffeeShop(americanCoffeeFactory);
        americanCoffeeShop.orderCoffee(CoffeeType.CAPPUCCINO);
    }
}
```

Не вижу особых преимуществ в данном случае, просто названия классов стали чуть короче.

Comment: А как быть если в конструкторе нужно принимать аргументы? Тогда ещё придется в иерархии самих строящихся объектов для всех прописывать конструктор, либо делать поля доступными для изменения извне

Comment: *"Преимущество фабричного метода"*.. по сравнению с чем?

Comment: Вообще цель если точнее.

Comment: **Вопрос не понятен**. Вы спрашиваете *"в чем преимущества станка производящего гайки?"* Преимущества по сравнению с чем? *"Вообще цель если точнее"* .... хммм... производить гайки, так-то..

Comment: Я же могу просто использовать обычный конструктор через new, зачем мне фабрика, вот вопрос.

Comment: В примерах которые я вижу просто используется фабрика где можно использовать new

Comment: Хотя можно и придумать пример, я просто не понимаю мне на работе не приходится использовать фабрики или я просто не понимаю как писать код так чтобы их использование само сабой приходило на ум

Comment: Приходят примеры на ум только если задавать определенные поля класса (или объекта) фабрики до передачи в другие методы. Потому что иначе либо смысла нет, можно прямо там использовать все равно никакой толковой информации не передается, либо это уже другой паттерн. Абстрактная фабрика например.

Comment: Приведите эти уточнения в тело вопроса (кнопка "править") и дополните примером кода, который вам кажется непонятным.

Comment: Внес правки с кодом

Comment: Нашел приминение упрощении создания. Если фабрика будет создавать конкретные модели продкута и создавать и/или передавать в конструктор нужные аргументы для создания этой модели. Например если конструктор сложный, например некоторые его аргументы это объекты с множеством параметров; либо просто чтобы понятнее было. Например вместо создания какой-то машины с какими-то параметрами будет метод создать BMW X5. И да возможно в обсуждении я где-то путал абстрактную фабрику и фабричный метод, но сейчас конкретно про фабричный метод пишу.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145402/discussion-between--and-kromster).

Comment: Судя по всему, ваш главный вопрос сводится к "Я узнал что такое чердак и стропила, зачем они мне нужны в квартире?". Вполне вероятно, что в вашей практике вам просто не нужны Фабричные Методы, вам их негде применить.

Comment: Возможно и так. Но это же ещё вопрос архитектуры решения. В любом случае ещё немного подожду и закрою вопрос.

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы, для меня это было важно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В моем понимании весь смысл фабрики сводится к инкапсуляции логики создания объектов. Этому можно найти массу применений, но пожалуй самое важное из них это реализация инверсии зависимостей. Просто сейчас за нас грязную работу проделывают DI-фреймворки.

Попробую привести банальный пример. Представьте, что вам надо написать кучу бизнес-логики, завязанной на отправку SMS, при этом вы скорее всего изучили предметную область и узнали, что смс-шлюзы бывают разные, поэтому сначала завели интерфейс `SmsService`, а уже потом сделали имплементацию под конкретного вендора - `SomeVendorSmsService`. Так вот, вы конечно можете ссылаться в бизнес-логике напрямую на наследника, но скорее всего захотите ссылаться только на интерфейс. Зачем? Чтобы в случае чего легко переехать на другого вендора, либо вообще использовать ту или иную реализацию в зависимости от обстоятельств (регион, оператор и т.п) А как вы будете этого достигать если у вас нет DI-фреймворка? Ну наверное вряд ли вы захотите дублировать всю эту логику при каждой необходимости просто отправить SMS. Тут то и нужна фабрика.

Comment: Я вроде и описал другими словами это. То есть мы прячем кучу кода для создания объекта в фабричном методе, вместо того чтобы каждый раз все руками прописывать. По поводу инверсии, можно и без фабрик создать интефейс для создаваемых объектов и указывать его как аргумент. Хотя вообще я вот только что прочитал про инверсию, может что-то не допонял.

Comment: А вы это не про абстрактную фабрику? Я тут про фабричный метод обсуждение веду